# How to map nested java objects in cassandra?

Tags: java, nosql, cassandra

I am exploring NoSQL options for write intensive device event logging service.

I found HBase and Cassandra are well suited for it and decided to explore Cassandra first.

As I come from ORM world, I am facing hard time mapping nested Java Entities into Cassandra.

Can someone guide me how to map following entity having reference to other entities using any java based Cassandra tool.DeviceInfo and DeviceEvent will have their own primary keys and other relevant fields

```
@Entity 
public class LogRequest {

@Id
private String id;

private DeviceInfo deviceInfo;

private Collection<DeviceEvent> deviceEvent;

// getters and setters

}
```

Appreciate your time and guidance.

Comment: This looks like a 1 to many implementation? Are you going to need to query deviceEvents for a set of different deviceInfo objects? Cassandra is not well suited to (nor supports) joins. You could probably do some deviceEvent info partitioned by something that identifies deviceInfo but we need more info on what either of these things are.

Comment: Yes, it is one-to-many relationship, According to you, I should consider restructuring of LogRequest object and define it like Map<DeviceInfo, Collection<DeviceEvent>>. So anything that can be structured in map style cassandra may be preferable. I have earlier considered MongoDB but as my use case is write intensive hence I started to look for other NoSQL options.

Comment: What are other alternatives to cop up with such requirement where I need to store information in document style and also provides high through-put in the application?

Comment: hector-object-mapper is my only ticket to solve this but still associations are not getting stored in database when I tried with that

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. Primitive values of the leaf level objects are mapped to Cassandra dynamic composite columns. Can handle 1 to 1 and 1 to many children objects at multiple levels. Primary key is defined using attributes of the root object.

https://pkghosh.wordpress.com/2013/07/14/storing-nested-objects-in-cassandra-composite_columns/